# Using `errc` or throw an exception

Tags: c++

The new `from_chars` function uses an `errc` instead of throwing an exception. The motivation is:

> Why do we not throw an exception on parse error? Two reasons: Exceptions come with a cost (in particular, when thrown), and a parse error is not an exceptional situation.

Other functions like `stoi` throw an exception while streams does both (throws an exception with info encoded in `io_errc`). Using the same argument, `stoi` should not throw exceptions either, although it follows the convention of using `std::out_of_range`. Does the future of C++ prefer to use `errc` wherever possible instead of exceptions? Is there an approach I should prefer?

Comment: The goals of `stoi` and `from_chars` are different, even if the end-result is the same (converting a string to an integer value).

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @buhtz And what exactly is wrong with my question?

Comment: @user167921 One thing: You have a quote, but you do not tell us where that quote come from. If possible, provide a link to where you found the quote. Attribution is important.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That help page says nothing about quotes, but thanks for the non-sequitor I guess?

Answer (score -1):

STL doesn't return `errc` it uses exceptions.

Also, exceptions comes at a cost if thrown. Checking return value of a function always costs something.

In general it looks like exceptions is a standard way to handle errors and IMO should be used by default.

You can read some info here http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0364r0.pdf

Also, you may read this stuff http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Re-throw

Comment: First of all, STL is the [Standard Template Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library), from which part of the standard library was inspired by. Secondly, the [`std::from_chars`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) function is new in the C++17 standard, and it does not throw an exception.